# Display pdf in xamarin android through api

Tags: c#, android, pdf, xamarin.android

I have an API which returns bytes and I'm converting this back to PDF. It opens up the PDF when I call the API from the Android App but when I download or send it in a email, the file type goes missing. file type doesn't come up as PDF. Am I missing something here? Any help is appreciated.

```
string filePath = "http://myurl.com/api/LGSR?jobId=" + txtJobID.Text + "&propId=" + txtPropId.Text;



                Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(filePath);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                intent.SetDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
                intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset | ActivityFlags.NewTask);

                try
                {
                    StartActivity(intent);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(ApplicationContext, "No Application Available to View PDF", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
```

Comment: Just from the code of your `filePath`, it should be the absolute path of your pdf file, but based on your code, I didn't see it ends with ".pdf" extension?